# tikz, overlay pgf pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have three tikz/pgf pictures which I want to overlay using something like that

```
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [yshift=5cm](0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\scalebox{0.71}{\input{figures/hahn_long.pgf}}
\scalebox{0.4}{\input{figures/hahn_short.pgf}}
```

but that doesn't work, since it draws the three pictures, one after another (even the `yshift` has no effect). How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try putting only the draw commands in the files and inputing them in the same TikZ-picture? Like `\begin{tikzpicture} \draw...; \input{} }input{} \input{figures/hahn_long.pgf}`?

Comment: yeah, not really, because the two .pgf pictures are created with python-matplotlib, and are therefore quite complicated, and not just simple `\draw...` commands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) it is a bit difficult to know what exactly shall be achieved here. However, if your goal is to horizontally overprint the context of your three figures, this can be achieved either using low-level TeX commands (`\llap{<content>}`, `\rlap{<content>}`) or, a bit more generic and less error-prone, LaTeX's `\makebox[<width>][<align>]{<content>}` command, with a zero value for the `<width>` parameter.

This [TUBboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf=AFQjCNENp6_ppqjakCEyQbooQry4T1o7Kg) provides a bit of background on these (and more) commands. In the following, I will use `\makebox`; in the last example additionally `\raisebox{<yshift>}{<content>}` to implement a vertical shift:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{xcolor}

  \newcommand{\figone}{{\color{black}\rule{4cm}{4cm}}}
  \newcommand{\figtwo}{{\color{red}\rule{3cm}{3cm}}}
  \newcommand{\figthree}{{\color{blue}\rule{2cm}{2cm}}}

  \begin{document}
    Text starts here:

    \makebox[0pt][l]{\figone}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\figtwo}%
    \figthree%

    \makebox[0pt][r]{\figone}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\figtwo}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\figthree}%

    Text ends here:

    \begin{center}
      Centered:

      \makebox[0pt][c]{\figone}%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{\figtwo}%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{\figthree}%

      Centered, y-shifted:

      \makebox[0pt][c]{\figone}%
      \raisebox{0.5cm}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\figtwo}}%
      \raisebox{1cm}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\figthree}}%

      And so on...
    \end{center}

  \end{document}
```

Lacking the real figures, I have substituted the tree figures by colored squares of different size. The output looks like following:

[image]